# KentorIT, SAML2, Okta, MVC Authentication - login issue

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, okta, kentor-authservices

I am a newbie, I have setup my MVC application that will use okta for Authentication, trying to achieve using KentorIT,
when the user isn't logged-In it redirects to Okta, and but Okta sent the response back, I am getting null in loginInfo object always.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

I have put my POC code at below Git Location,

https://github.com/psharepoint10/MVC-okta-KentorIT

I think I am doing some small mistake in configuration/settings.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant code (such as the Kentor AuthServices config in your Startup.Auth.cs) directly here.

Comment: I am also having the exact same issue on an integration environment. Locally ... all is working fine!

When I check Fiddler I can see the SAML response - and all looks fine!

Any ideas?